# How to make a gap in navbar

Tags: html, css

I have bulid the nav bar which works perfectly .But now I am trying to make a transparent gap between the black bar and text(shop, contact,program,others). How can I do it . In the picture I create the black using border.

[image]

Comment: Please add all the relevant code. A working snippet is the best.

Comment: You cannot add a gap between a border and the red. Well, technically you can, but not the way you're attempting. I'll post a solution

Comment: You should add some code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could have added some code. However, considering that your code is something like this:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="item">HOME</div>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="item">HOME</div>
        <div class="item">CONTACT</div>
        <div class="item">PROGRAM</div>
        <div class="item">OTHERS</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could add margin from the top to the inner (white) items like this:

```
.inner{
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your submenu (with "shop", "contact", etc), try this:
*Note: You need to change the `li` selector to match your specific case, just add `::before` and MAKE SURE your actual `li` has a position (you can set this to `position: relative` if it doesn't already have one)

```
li::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 2px;
  top: 0;
  left: -10px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

And remove the border from your current `li`.